# Expanding asterisk in glob

Tags: python, linux, glob

I want to be able to print a list of all file in a directory in linux but my code only print out the first item in the directory

inside home directory is text1.txt, text2.txt, text3.txt

`sys.argv[1]` should be /`home/*` when I run it on command line:

```
python fileName.py /home/*
```

Script:

```
def list_file():
    listFile= glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
    return listFile

print list_file()
```

the output is only the first file in the directory

```
 ['text1.txt']
```

any idea? The code works fine on Windows but when I moved it to Linux, it doesn't work anymore

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the shell expands the wildcard, you don't need to call `glob`. Just print all the arguments in `sys.argv`

```
def list_file():
    return sys.argv[1:]

print list_file()
```

Answer (score 6):

The way you are calling the script, the `*` gets expanded by Bash itself, so by saying

```
python fileName.py /home/*
```

this gets expanded into

```
python fileName.py /home/file1 /home/file2 /home/file3
```

so `sys.argv[1]` is just `/home/file1`.

To make it work, add the `*` in the Python script:

```
import sys
import glob

def list_file():
    return glob.glob(sys.argv[1] + '*')

print list_file()
```

and run like `python fileName.py /home/`.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes. Shell runs first parameter as command. You can see this using "*print sys.argv[1]*"

```
python fileName.py "/home/*"
```